# How to announce "not to say mashiv haruach" since such an announcement is improper?

Tags: geshem-tal-ruach, gabbai

The Mishnah Berurah (114:3) [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.114.3):

> ולהכריז להדיא שיפסקו מלומר מוריד הגשם ג"כ אין נכון מפני שנראה כממאנים בגשמים ... ע"כ פסק הרמ"א בס"ג שנוהגין שלא להפסיק מלהזכיר גשם עד תפלת המנחה ששמעו כבר מש"ץ שפסק בתפלת מוסף

Freely translated:

> [For those who do not say "Morid HaTal" in the summer] it would not be correct to announce "stop saying 'Morid HaGeshem'" because it would appear that we are "refusing" the rain .... Therefore, the Rema says to continue saying "Morid HaGeshem" at Mussaf, and to stop saying it at Mincha because we heard the Chazzan stop saying it at Mussaf [and that acts as an announcement to stop saying it].

Given the above, are there any *poskim* who discuss what to do in shul at Mincha if there are less-knowledgeable people who need an explicit announcement that they should be changing something in their davening from how they were doing it the day before?

Comment: Probably best is to go over to them individually, since it's the announcement that is problematic

Comment: What's wrong with "we stopped saying Mashiv Haruach this morning"? That's not a command. The problem is telling people to stop, not announcing that we've stopped. Surely if someone asks three weeks later 'are we still mentioning rain' you can say no.

Comment: Anyway you can avoid the question entirely since the Rama's problem is with announcing to stop mentioning rain. There is definitely no problem with announcing to stop mentioning wind and for better or worse most people won't notice the difference. Wind can be recited or not recited all summer or winter or both or neither and it won't help or ruin your prayer.

Comment: @DoubleAA Many people who say morid hatol also mention wind in summer. So it would be wrong to say stop mentioned wind. The simple answer is like it says if you say 90 times 'rav lheshia mechalkel chaim' you wont forget. I dont know why they cant call out to say this at mussaph,.

Comment: @interested If they say morid hatal then you can just announce remember to say morid hatal. The case was clearly somewhere that doesn't say morid hatal in the summer.

Comment: @DoubleAA But the same reason for not saying 'dont say morid hagoshom' should apply even more so to morid hatol.

Comment: @interested Sure, but no one is telling you to stop saying morid hatal either.

Comment: @DoubleAA My mistake I meant one cant say stop mentioning mashiv horuach for the same reason as morid hagoshim and even more so.

Comment: @interested Why not?